# How to execute .bat files using Finalbuilder?

Tags: finalbuilder

I am using Finalbuilder to build packages. I want to execute `.bat` using file content iterator. Can I use anything other than file content iterator to execute .bat files?

Answer (score 1):

FinalBuilder has specific action, called [Run DOS Command](http://help.finalbuilder.com/Index.htm?rundoscommand.htm). And it is used to

> ...execute any native DOS command or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of FinalBuilder are you using?

You can use the Execute Program action. The program file would be cmd.exe, the path to your batch file goes as parameter.

E.g.: cmd.exe /C script.bat